# MySql query or merge array into 1

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, wordpress

Im using ACF Pro, in database `wp_postmeta` I had 2 `meta_key`: `dich_vu_%_name_service` and `dich_vu_%_price_service`. Both had value , so how can I query and return it as (`dich_vu_%_name_service,dich_vu_%_price_service`). Or if MySQL cant handle it so how can i merge 2 arrays of those query into one like this?

```
array(objects(['name_service'] => Test,['price_service'] => 9999))
```

here is my code i tried

```
function getAllFaqs() {
global $wpdb;
    $results = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( 
    "SELECT DISTINCT meta_value FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts,{$wpdb->prefix}postmeta WHERE meta_key LIKE %s AND post_name = %s",
    'dich_vu_%_name_service',
    'bang-gia-dich-vu'
));
    $results2 = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( 
    "SELECT DISTINCT meta_value FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts,{$wpdb->prefix}postmeta WHERE meta_key LIKE %s AND post_name = %s",
    'dich_vu_%_price_service',
    'bang-gia-dich-vu'
));

    $array = array();
    foreach ($results as $result) {
        $array[]['name_service'] = $result->meta_value;
    }
    $array = $array;
    $array2 = array();
    foreach ($results2 as $result2) {
        $array2[]['price_service'] = $result2->meta_value;
    }
    $array2 = $array2;
    $array3 = array_combine($array,$array2);
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

**Union** is your friend, you can combine the two queries (keep in mind that both result sets must have the same number of columns and the same type and in order):

```
$query1 = $wpdb->prepare( 
    "SELECT DISTINCT meta_value FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts,{$wpdb->prefix}postmeta WHERE meta_key LIKE %s AND post_name = %s",
    'dich_vu_%_name_service',
    'bang-gia-dich-vu'
);
$query2 = $wpdb->prepare( 
    "SELECT DISTINCT meta_value FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts,{$wpdb->prefix}postmeta WHERE meta_key LIKE %s AND post_name = %s",
    'dich_vu_%_price_service',
    'bang-gia-dich-vu'
);

$results = $wpdb->get_results( $query1.' UNION '.$query2);
```

Check the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html)

P.S: I do not know wordpress but saw that [prepare](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/#return) returns the sanitized query string so a UNION in between should work

Answer (score 0):

Why you make it as much complex. Simply use like this as WordPress standard

```
global $wpdb;
// Instead of passing post slug, you need to use post id here
$myvals1 = get_post_meta($post->ID,"dich_vu_%_name_service", true);
$myvals2 = get_post_meta($post->ID,"dich_vu_%_price_service", true);

$obj = new StdClass();
$obj->name_service = $myvals1;  
$obj->price_service = $myvals2;  

$res = array($obj);

// result 
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#245 (2) {
    ["name_service"]=>
    string(4) "Test"
    ["price_service"]=>
    string(4) "9999"
  }
}
```

Comment: array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#2145 (2) {
    ["name_service"]=>
    array(6) {
      [0]=>
      object(stdClass)#2157 (1) {
        ["meta_value"]=>
        string(3) "ACF"
      }
      [1]=>
      object(stdClass)#2156 (1) {
        ["meta_value"]=>
        string(24) "Triple Test"
      }
    }
    ["price_service"]=>
    array(6) {
      [0]=>
      object(stdClass)#2151 (1) {
        ["meta_value"]=>
        string(6) "15000"
      }
      [1]=>
      object(stdClass)#2150 (1) {
        ["meta_value"]=>
        string(7) "19000"
      }
    }
  }
}

Comment: It showed me like that.But i want like this:array(2) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#2145 (2) {
    ["name_service"]=>string(3) "ACF"
    ["price_service"]=>string(6) "150000"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#2145 (2) {
    ["name_service"]=>string(3) "Triple Test"
    ["price_service"]=>string(6) "150000"
  }
}

Comment: Could you let me know 'bang-gia-dich-vu' post have how many mata key's like 'dich_vu_%_name_service'?. Because Meta key of a single post is unique.. You want to merge all two keys from all posts right?

Comment: It's may have few hundress or few thousands dich_vu_%_name_service and dich_vu_%_price_service, but bang-gia-dich-vu was just a page which i was using ACF repeater fields.It's store name services and price of services.I just want to merge all values of dich_vu_%_name_service and dich_vu_%_price_service into one like the format above so i can loop it and get the data to the html table.

Comment: I just want to merge only one post/page.

Comment: Please refer this link. He gave more options.. https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_fields/